# Find non-empty string in nested object

Tags: javascript

In the following object called 'task', the `door` property could arbitrary each time:

```
var task = {};

task["123"] = [{"door":""}, {"door":""},  {"door":""}, {"door":""}];
task["456"] = [{"door":""}, {"door":"close"},  {"door":""}, {"door":""}];
task["789"] = [{"door":""}, {"door":""},  {"door":""}, {"door":""}];
```

Let's say we need to find if there is an entry in the task object which has an array item with a property not equal to "". So in the above, there is only one such entry and its value is "close".

One could use nested for loops which bail out as soon as a non empty value is found. How else could one do it? (maybe using LINQ to create shorter code?)

Comment: LINQ doesn't exist in JavaScript

Comment: So you only need to know if a non-empty value exists? Not it's top-level key?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ belongs to C# not JS. But you can use ES6 syntax e. g. a [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) after a [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) if you want to detect if there's a `door !== ""`:

```js
var task = {};
task["123"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["456"] = [{door: ""}, {door: "close"}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["789"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];

const hasNonEmptyDoor = Object.values(task)
  .flat()
  .some(item => item.door !== "");

console.log(hasNonEmptyDoor);
```

Comment: Nested loop is avoidable with `flat`

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with several `Object::values` and `Array::some` in a chain:

```js
var task = {};
task["123"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["456"] = [{door: ""}, {door: "close"}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["789"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];

const hasNonEmptyProp = Object.values(task).some(task => task.some(task => Object.values(task).some(val => val !== '')));

console.log(hasNonEmptyProp);
```

One crazy way would be to use a regex if you need the smallest code. It's possible to regex only the arrays which is actually faster than flatting the whole object:

```js
var task = {};
task["123"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["456"] = [{door: ""}, {door: "close"}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["789"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];

const hasNonEmptyProp = /":[^"]+"/.test(JSON.stringify(task));

console.log(hasNonEmptyProp);
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="200000">

var task = {};
task["123"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["456"] = [{door: ""}, {door: "close"}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];
task["789"] = [{door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}, {door: ""}];

// @benchmark Behemoth
Object.values(task)
  .flat()
  .some(item => item.door !== "");
  
// @benchmark Alexander
Object.values(task).some(task => task.some(task => Object.values(task).some(val => val !== '')));

// @benchmark regex
Object.values(task).some(task => /"[^"]+"/.test(JSON.stringify(task)));
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```